# css grid row height bound to view width

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass

For any element this works perfectly `height: clamp(100px, 2.5vw, 150px)` which sets a minimum,a growing rate and a maximum height.
How could we implement the `clamp(MIN, VAL, MAX)` css function to a row height ?

```css
body {
  background: whitesmoke;
  border: solid black 1px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
  grid-template-rows: 125px;
  gap: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.box {
  background-color: tomato;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

</head>

<body>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean like this? Setting box to 100% height and then just using the clamp property in grid-template-rows.

```css
body {
  background: whitesmoke;
  border: solid black 1px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
  grid-template-rows: clamp(300px, 3vh, 800px);
  gap: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.box {
  background-color: tomato;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

</head>

<body>
  
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>

</body>

</html>
```